# Timestamp object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, pandas

Sometimes when I'm running a python code in Google Colab and it runs in the first place, turns out that in the 2nd or 3rd attempt this same chunk of code for unknown reasons gives an error, as if the code was wrong (even though nothing has been modified). As soon as I disconnect and restart the notebook, the exact same chunk of code runs normally, again without modifications. Has anyone already come across this issue and know how to fix it?

```
import datetime #1st chunk

def convert_date(x): #2nd chunk
  y= x.split(' ')[0]
  return datetime.datetime(int(y.split('/')[2]),int(y.split('/')[1]),int(y.split('/')[0]))

hr['Hire Date'] = hr['Hire Date'].map(lambda x: convert_date(x)) #3rd chunk
```

When running the 3rd chunk it gives the error: `AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'split'`

Comment: Please provide the code that you are running. Most likely the code changes the starting conditions such that following runs no longer work, but we can't tell without seeing your code.

Comment: Can you include the code and the error message in the question?

Comment: @MichaelCao just uploaded it

Comment: Yeah, you are redefining `hr['Hire Date']` on the first run, so the second run will be different. You can see this by adding a `print(hr['Hire Date'])` at the beginning. You'll see that it prints a different output from 1st to 2nd run.

Comment: Since you're replacing the value of `hr['Hire Date']`, on the 2nd run it is running on an already converted value. And similarly, in further runs, the value keeps getting converted several times over.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. You need to load `hr` in the "first or third chunk"

Comment: Great! Tks very much guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is because you already applied the transformation to that column. Reload your data instead of restarting the kernel and it will work again.